# dompdf laravel on live server, can't download pdf and return error 500

Tags: laravel, web-hosting, dompdf

I hosted my Laravel Project to 000webhost, my project can make report in pdf format. I use dompdf to do all pdf things. When in my localhost server (xampp), dompdf works fine with no error and rendering html very well. In live server i got error 500 "Whoops, something went wrong on our servers.". I can't find any solution, i thought it was execution time, i rise it to 2000 seconds still got 500.

here is my controller

```
public function retur_preport(Request $request)
  {
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '2000');
    ini_set('memory_limit','512M');

    $tgl1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('tanggal_mulai')));
    $tgl2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('sampai_tanggal')));

    if($tgl1 > date('Y-m-d') || $tgl2 > date('Y-m-d')){
      return redirect('upper/laporan/retur')->with('error','Tanggal yang diinput tidak bisa lebih besar dari '.date('d M Y').' (hari ini)');
    }elseif($tgl2 != '1970-01-01' && $tgl1 > $tgl2){
      return redirect('upper/laporan/retur')->with('error','Tanggal mulai tidak bisa lebih besar dari inputan tanggal sampai');
    }elseif($tgl1 == '1970-01-01' && $tgl2 == '1970-01-01'){
      return redirect('upper/laporan/retur')->with('error','Salah satu dari kedua tanggal harus diisi');
    }elseif($tgl1 == '1970-01-01'){
      $r = \App\Retur::whereDate('tgl_retur',$tgl2)->orderBy('tgl_retur','desc')->get();
      $pdf = PDF::loadview('pimpinan/laporan/retur/report', compact('r','tgl1','tgl2'))->setPaper('a4','landscape');
      return $pdf->download('laporan retur tanggal '.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($tgl2)).'.pdf');
    }elseif($tgl2 == '1970-01-01'){
      $r = \App\Retur::whereBetween('tgl_retur',[$tgl1, date('Y-m-d')])->orderBy('tgl_retur','desc')->get();
      $pdf = PDF::loadview('pimpinan/laporan/retur/report',compact('r','tgl1','tgl2'))->setPaper('a4','landscape');
      return $pdf->download('laporan retur tanggal '.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($tgl1)).' sampai tanggal '.date('d-M-Y').'.pdf');
    }else{
      $r = \App\Retur::whereBetween('tgl_retur',[$tgl1,$tgl2])->orderBy('tgl_retur','desc')->get();
      $pdf = PDF::loadview('pimpinan/laporan/retur/report', compact('r','tgl1','tgl2'))->setPaper('a4','landscape');
      return $pdf->download('laporan retur tanggal '.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($tgl1)).' sampai tanggal '.date('d-M-Y', strtotime($tgl2)).'.pdf');
    }
  }
```

and here is my html that rendered from controller

```
<html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets') }}/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets') }}/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets') }}/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets') }}/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
     folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets') }}/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">

<style>
  .no-gutters {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;

    > .col,
    > [class*="col-"] {
      padding-right: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
    }
  }

  table, td, th, tr, thead, tbody {
    border: 1px solid black !important;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="content-header row text-center">
  <img src="{{ asset('uploads') }}/kadatuan_logo/logo.jpg" width="120" height="120"><br>
  Jl. Karawitan No. 48, Bandung
</div>
<section class="content">
  <div class="box box-primary box-solid">
    <div class="box-header">
        Laporan Retur
        @if($tgl1 == '1970-01-01')
          Tanggal <strong>{{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($tgl2)) }}</strong>
        @elseif($tgl2 == '1970-01-01')
          Tanggal <strong>{{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($tgl1)) }}</strong> Sampai <strong>{{ date('d-M-Y') }}</strong>
        @else
          Tanggal <strong>{{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($tgl1)) }}</strong> Sampai <strong>{{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($tgl2)) }}</strong>
        @endif
        <div class="pull-right">Dicetak pada tanggal <strong>{{ date('d-M-Y') }}</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <table class="table text-center">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>ID Pemesanan</th>
              <th>ID Retur</th>
              <th>Tanggal Retur</th>
              <th>Nama Mitra</th>
              <th>Barang Retur</th>
              <th>Jumlah Retur</th>
              <th>Status Retur</th>
              <th>Keterangan</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           @foreach ($r as $row)
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="{{ \App\DRetur::where('id_retur',$row->id_retur)->count() }}">{{ !empty($i) ? ++$i : $i = 1}}</td>
              <td rowspan="{{ \App\DRetur::where('id_retur',$row->id_retur)->count() }}">{{ $row->id_pemesanan }}</td>
              <td rowspan="{{ \App\DRetur::where('id_retur',$row->id_retur)->count() }}">{{ $row->id_retur }}</td>
              <td rowspan="{{ \App\DRetur::where('id_retur',$row->id_retur)->count() }}">{{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row->tgl_retur)) }}</td>
              <td rowspan="{{ \App\DRetur::where('id_retur',$row->id_retur)->count() }}">{{ $row->mitra->nama_mitra }}</td>
              @foreach (\App\DRetur::where('id_retur',$row->id_retur)->limit(1)->get() as $row2)
                <td>{{ \App\TPemesanan::join('t_dpemesanan','t_tpemesanan.id_dpemesanan','=','t_dpemesanan.id_dpemesanan')->join('t_stock','t_dpemesanan.id_stock','=','t_stock.id_stock')->where('t_tpemesanan.id_tpemesanan',$row2->id_tpemesanan)->first()->nama_stock }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row2->jumlah_dretur }}{{ \App\TPemesanan::join('t_dpemesanan','t_tpemesanan.id_dpemesanan','=','t_dpemesanan.id_dpemesanan')->join('t_stock','t_dpemesanan.id_stock','=','t_stock.id_stock')->where('t_tpemesanan.id_tpemesanan',$row2->id_tpemesanan)->first()->satuan }}</td>
                  @if( $row2->status_dretur == 1 )
                    <td>Menunggu Diperiksa</td>
                  @elseif( $row2->status_dretur == 2 )
                    <td>Diterima</td>
                  @elseif( $row2->status_dretur == 3 )
                    <td>Ditolak</td>
                  @endif
                <td>{{ $row2->keterangan }}</td>
              </tr>
              @foreach(\App\DRetur::where('id_retur',$row->id_retur)->get() as $row3)
                @if($row2->id_dretur != $row3->id_dretur)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ \App\TPemesanan::join('t_dpemesanan','t_tpemesanan.id_dpemesanan','=','t_dpemesanan.id_dpemesanan')->join('t_stock','t_dpemesanan.id_stock','=','t_stock.id_stock')->where('t_tpemesanan.id_tpemesanan',$row3->id_tpemesanan)->first()->nama_stock }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row3->jumlah_dretur }}{{ $row2->jumlah_dretur }}{{ \App\TPemesanan::join('t_dpemesanan','t_tpemesanan.id_dpemesanan','=','t_dpemesanan.id_dpemesanan')->join('t_stock','t_dpemesanan.id_stock','=','t_stock.id_stock')->where('t_tpemesanan.id_tpemesanan',$row3->id_tpemesanan)->first()->satuan }}</td>
                    @if( $row3->status_dretur == 1 )
                      <td>Menunggu Diperiksa</td>
                    @elseif( $row3->status_dretur == 2 )
                      <td>Diterima</td>
                    @elseif( $row3->status_dretur == 3 )
                      <td>Ditolak</td>
                    @endif
                  <td>{{ $row3->keterangan }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endif
              @endforeach
            @endforeach
           @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer">
      Sistem Informasi Supply
      <div class="pull-right">
        Hormat Saya, <strong>Reyhan (Admin)</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-footer-->
  </div>
      <!-- /.box -->
</section>
<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets') }}/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets') }}/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets') }}/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets') }}/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets') }}/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets') }}/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebar-menu').tree()
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Check your server logs for the reasons for the error.

Comment: Check permissions, server logs.  Not real familiar with Laravel, but I've had some problems with autoloading of classes sometimes also.  Here is another thing that I ran into with another MVC framework.  There was an issue with case sensitivity in the URL's that I was using.  e.g. domain.com/admin/index gave a 500 error, but domain.com/Admin/index did not.  That must have been related to the framework I was using (probably), but fixing the case fixed the problem.  I was using MAMP on a Mac (not case sensitive) whereas my hosting service is.

Comment: I actually kind of like that now because the controllers have an uppercase whereas the views have a lower case.  Makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @ceeyajoz how i do that? I use free version of 000webhost, is it something to do with it? I'm new from using live server

Comment: @sscotti permission for file is rw-r-r and for folder is rwx-rx-rx, and what should i do about that case sensitivity?

Comment: That probably is not the problem (the case thing).  I just mention that because I had an issue like that that took awhile to figure out.  If you are using a Mac with XAMPP you might still consider that.

Comment: The built-in artisan server is more than enough for developing, at least in my cases. You can find the log file in storage/logs/laravel.log. Please apend the latest stacktrace to your question.

Comment: i found the log, this is my error `[2019-07-12 00:15:02] production.ERROR: Undefined index:  {"userId":**,"email":"****@******.com","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index:  at /storage/ssd5/387/10173387/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php:3923)` wha is that mean?